# ILNumerics copy float array to ILArray

Tags: c#, arrays, copy, ilnumerics

I have 3 dimensional array of `floats` and i want copy them to `ILArray<float>`, but how?

```
private float[,,] defArray = new float[10, 10, 3];
private ILArray<float> data;
```

Array.Copy doesn't work on this. I know i can create ILArray directly and populate it with values, but i really need copy my array to ILArray. Thank all of you.

Answer (score 0):

according to http://ilnumerics.net/ArrayCreation4.html it should work by simply assigning the System.Array to the ILArray:

```
data = defArray;
```

Comment: I have already tried this, but it doesn't work. 3D data are corrupted after copy. Problem is, that i have huge array and direct populating inside for loop is slow. I've tried to populate classic array and it's much more faster. So that's the reason i want to try copy data from array to ILArray.

Comment: what you mean by corrupted? You may file a bug report, if you find corrupted data?